# c define multiline macro?

Tags: c, macros

```
#define DEBUG_BREAK(a)\
    if ((a)) \
{\
    __asm int 3;\
}
```

I have defined a macro as above, and try to use it

```
#include "test_define.h"
int main()
{
    DEBUG_BREAK(1 == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

But this sample will not compile. The compiler would complain the parenthesis is not closed. If I add another `}` in the end of the source file, it compiles.

What's wrong with this macro?

Comment: It seems likely that there is nothing wrong with the macro, but with some other part of the code. However, icky macros like this one are a pain to trouble-shoot, so that's what's wrong with it. Write a function instead.

Comment: Please do not tag questions with C and C++ when you reference just C in the title.

Comment: Nothing's fatally wrong with the code you illustrate, but maybe there's a missing `}` in the `#include`d test_define.h?

Comment: Ask your compiler to generate the proprocessed output (e.g. `gcc -E`) and inspect it.

Comment: It is odd that the compiler is complaining about unclosed parenthesis, but it is a close brace that fixes the problem.  Maybe you should show (a minimal version of) the complete header and the actual compiler error.

Comment: @Lundin Consider Readability vs. Performance. The approach given here can lead to better-optimised code. Consider `get`, `put`, `del` functions for a collection. All need to `seek` existing elements, but when they find the sought element they react in different ways. On `seek` success, we must check the success condition, then break/return from an inline function; in users of that function, we then need to RE-check the results to see what we need to do in each case. Wasteful? With a multi-line `SEEK` macro 2 conditionals become 1, by including follow-up code directly where the loop terminates.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer It is extremely unlikely that you'll ever encounter a situation where such manual micro-optimizations matter. But it is extremely likely you'll encounter a situation where readability and maintenance matters.

Comment: @Lundin Interesting you should say that, since I've just recently written a special-purpose map collection where it absolutely did matter. There is nothing wrong with alerting others to pitfalls, but rigid commentary on "what not to do" tends ultimately to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The macro

```
#define DEBUG_BREAK(a)\
    if ((a)) \
    __asm int 3;
```

works fine but

```
#define DEBUG_BREAK(a)\
    if ((a)) \
{\
    __asm int 3;\
}
```

doesn't! And I think anyone could guess why!! The new line operator is the problem making guy!

It takes

```
 __asm int 3;\
}
```

as

```
__asm int 3; }
```

where `;` comments out what follows it (in assembly). So we will miss a `}` then.

Answer (score 7):

Check there is no white space after each backslash. I often fall for this.

You might even need a single space before the backslash.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define DEBUG_BREAK(a)\
if ((a)) \
{\
    __asm \
    { \
        int 3;\
    } \
}
```

Or.... (since you are on Windows, just use the DebugBreak function...)

```
#define DEBUG_BREAK(a) {if ((a)) DebugBreak();}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, but getting {int 3} into brackets helps. And combining macro into singleliner doesn't. So it should be something about assembly, not the multilining.

Comment: Hm. But not in VC6. Can you please try bracketing assembly in your studio?

Comment: Offtopic but important: don't use VC6 for anything. It's old, outdated and, most importantly, full of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it as an inline function:

```
inline void DEBUG_BREAK(bool b)
{
    if (b) 
    {
        __asm int 3
    }
}
```

You may want to replace `__asm int 3` with `DebugBreak()`, as that is the official MS function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
#define DEBUG_BREAK(a)\
    if ((a)) \
    __asm int 3;
```