# asm block in c++ as a macro

Tags: c++, assembly, macros

I would like to write a macro which converts everything to void* even the member functions.
Here is the code:

```
#define toVoidStar(xx,yy)\
    __asm push ecx; \
    __asm mov ecx, yy; \ 
    __asm mov [xx], ecx; \ 
    __asm pop ecx;
```

end it gives the error when I "call it": error C2017: illegal escape

if I use it in the code it just works fine:

```
void * myvoid;

__asm
{
    push ecx;
    mov ecx, imageMousePressed;
    mov [myvoid], ecx;
    pop ecx;
}
```

I know this is not a very nice solution but anyway can anybody help to get it work?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you want to do this? void* (void pointer) is possible without any assembler for everything.

Comment: It wouldn't work due to the assembly semicolon. Maybe you should try rewriting it as a template function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot give a macro definition like:

```
#define toVoidStar(xx,yy)\
    __asm push ecx; \
    __asm mov ecx, yy; \ 
    __asm mov [xx], ecx; \ 
    __asm pop ecx;
```

since all the lines after the line `__asm push ecx;` will be commented out because of the `;` used. See my answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685211/c-define-multiline-macro/16685840#16685840).

Comment: thanks. Is there any way to get it work? The inline function is not good in this case because I don't know the type of the xx.

Comment: You just want to move 4 bytes to the location pointed by the address in `myvoid`, right?

Comment: yes, but I cannot do void * myvoid = &eventHandlerFunct because it is a member function. Anyway the other answer the union hack works fine but I still curious whether my solution can work somehow or not.

Comment: So, if you want to try your own solution, why can't you make it an `inline` function!

Comment: template<class T>
inline void* as_void2(T const x)
{
 void * myVoid;
 __asm
 {
  push ecx;
  mov ecx, x;
  mov myVoid, ecx;
  pop ecx;
 }
 return &myVoid;
}

Comment: sorry about the previous using an inline function I could get my solution get work as well. Thank very much for both of you.

Answer (score 8):

Why not standart union hack?

```
template<class T>
void* as_void(T const & x)
{
   union hlp_t{
      void * v_ptr;
      T t;
   };
   hlp_t a;
   a.t = x;
   return a.v_ptr;
}
```

Usage: `as_void(&std::vector<int>::size)`

Comment: Er, are you sure that should be `T` in the union, and not `T*`?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Yep, in my example T -> void (std::vector<int>::*)(int), so T is exactly what needs to be cast, and T* would yield pointer to pointer

Answer (score 2):

Because the __asm keyword is a statement separator, you can also put assembly instructions on the same line ([see this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz.aspx)):

```
__asm mov al, 2   __asm mov dx, 0xD007   __asm out dx, al
```

So the solution is to just leave out the semicolons and the compiler will know where the statements end.

Comment: To clarify for myself, you'd just remove the semicolons at the end of each "line" in the macro?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Yes exactly.